# innodb_lock_wait_timeout value for best performance?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I'm trying to max out TPS of mysql server. If a transaction terminates early because of the small innodb_lock_wait_timeout value (e.g. 5), is this considered a completed transaction, thus increasing TPS?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions don't terminate when a lock wait times out. The transaction remains active, it's only one SQL statement that times out. You can retry that SQL statement, or you can commit the transaction without doing that unfinished SQL statement, or you can rollback the transaction and anything done earlier in that transaction will be undone.

If you were to design your code to react to a timeout by committing your transaction, I wouldn't call that a completed transaction.

Here's an analogy:

Suppose you run a restaurant, and you are concerned that customers wait too long for their food. The list of orders to do keeps getting too long. To make the kitchen's list of orders to do shorter, you tell the kitchen if an order has been waiting for more than 60 seconds, then cancel the order.

I think you will have a lot of hungry customers.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a transaction that takes longer than 5 seconds to complete is taking too long.

The work performed before the timeout is wasted.  In that sense, timing out hurts "performance".

Where does the TPS number come from?  Or where does it get the number from?

I would guess `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Com_commit';`

Comment: I'm using sysbench for benchmarking, but not yet figured how sysbench calculates TPS. My assumption is that if lots of transactions terminate because of short lock timeout, TPS will increase. Of course it is not the desired scenario in real business, though.